# Google Sheet Circular Dependency Issue With If Function

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Am using `if` function in Column A of the Google Sheets

`=ARRAYFORMULA(if( isblank(D3:D) , A2:A , D3:D ))`

but getting Circular dependency error. If I use the same function without `ARRAYFORMULA` i.e.

`if( isblank(D3) , A2 , D3 ))))`

and then drag the formula, there is no error and the result is reflected.

Any help on how to fix the Circular dependency error with `ARRAYFORMULA` in above case would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you are using `ARRAYFORMULA` in Column A with if condition in which you are using the reference of col A ...that is the reason you are getting Circular dependency error

Comment: used this formula in another column it will work

Comment: Thanks for the reply.... but if I use the formula in another column then how will the result be generated in column A?

Comment: I recommend that you share a link to your spreadsheet (or to a copy of it, or to a realistic representative sample from it). I suspect that you can rework the formula in Column A and avoid the circular dependency. But without being able to see your data and layout, and to understand your end goal, it isn't efficient to just guess. If you do decide to share that link, be sure to set the link's Share permission to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor."

Comment: Here is the link of the sheet as required...  

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fB31msHFWDVv9eweb2H0XJ6zDfpKjxEZG9bpXb36_44/edit?usp=sharing

Regards

Answer (score 2):

> When you see the circular dependency detected error displayed in your
> Google spreadsheet, this means that your formula is referring to a
> range that contains the formula itself, or in other words when the
> formula input, is dependent on the output.

What you can try to do is turning on Iterative Calculation under `File -> Settings`:

[image: setting iterative calculation]

If that fixes your issue then good. But based on your formula, I don't think this is a fix. The above option is best on recalculating values repetitively. Your current formula is not doing that.

If that's the case, then you'll just have to put the formula on another column to avoid the circular dependency.

I recommend you try and see the reference below about circular dependency and it might help you decide what you should do.

#### Reference:

- [Circular Dependency](https://www.spreadsheetclass.com/circular-dependency-detected-error-in-google-sheets/)