# Google Sheet Importrange With Round

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to import few columns of one Google sheet to another using importrange and want to import the numeric columns with roundup the value, is there any way to import the numeric column after roundup the source data.

Comment: First import, then roundup. Give examples Edyphant. Also accept good answers like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66760820/google-sheet-issue-in-if-function-with-array-formula) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66473889/google-sheet-circular-dependency-issue-with-if-function)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, just confirming, do you mean that first import the data without rounding off and then to round off the imported date?

Comment: Exactly @Edyphant.

Comment: Please consider clarifying the input data and the desired outcome, either via screenshots or by providing a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on (free of sensitive information).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be implemented; please follow below logic:

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("Source sheet link","Details!D2:E"),IMPORTRANGE("Source sheet link","Details!I2:I"),IMPORTRANGE("Source sheet link","Details!K2:K"),IMPORTRANGE("Source sheet link","Details!AA2:AA"),{IMPORTRANGE("Source sheet link","Details!Z2:Z2");Arrayformula(ROUND(IMPORTRANGE("Source sheet link","Details!Z3:Z"),0))},IMPORTRANGE("Source sheet link","Details!AB2:AB")},"Select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7 Where (Col3 = 'Indian Customs'  or Col3 = 'INDIAN CUSTOMS') and (Col2 = 'Oct-23' or Col2 = 'Nov-23')  order by Col1")
```

Comment: I have added appropriate "code fences" to your post but you should consider adding some better formatting to the code, like some line breaks and indentation.

Comment: Noted, Thanks Adrian